# Before_filter not calling method, setting local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

I'm trying to set a variable in my before_filter, but always get the error "undefined local variable or method 'question' for AnswersController":

```
    class AnswersController < ApplicationController
        before_filter :get_question

        def create
            @answer = question.answers.new(params[:answer])
            @answer.user = current_user
            @answer.save
            flash[:notice] = 'Answer posted successfully.'
            redirect_to request.referer
        end

            def get_question
                question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
            end
    end
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: When I make the assignment into the 'create' action, the code works fine...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make it an instance variable using the `@` symbol. Also, you may want to consider moving this into a private method (see below) since this most likely is not a public action.

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :get_question

    def create
        @answer = @question.answers.new(params[:answer])
        @answer.user = current_user
        @answer.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Answer posted successfully.'
        redirect_to request.referer
    end

    private

    def get_question
        @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    end
end
```

Comment: Maybe you also want to specify this before filter only for create action: `before_filter :get_question, only: :create`.

Comment: @peresleguine, I didn't include the suggestion because I figured that they most likely had only posted a partial controller and that there were other CRUD actions.